# Are tags part of JPEG file?

Tags: window, jpeg, file-management, photo-management

I have a winodws 8 Laptop. If I put tags in my jpegs, can I use these tags to search jpeg files on other windows / linux machines? Or I have to use specific application to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags are supported by the JPEG format. Windows 8 supports the standard. You will be able to use these tags on other Windows and Linux machines.

For more information, you can see this post: http://beckustech.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/tagging-jpeg-image-files/

Answer (score 2):

For some background. JPEG does not define a file format. There are a number of file formats that have been defined for JPEG images. JFIF, SPIFF, ADOBE, and EXIF are examples of such formats.

The JPEG standard defines APP0-APPF (hex) markers for applications to store metadata. Their structure is not defined by JPEG. The various file formats use some of these markers. The rest can be used by applications.

The EXIF format defines various tags that you can use with that format.
JFIF does not have tags but has some limited metadata.

The answer then is that the various file formats allow the storage of metadata either within their own structures, tags, or unreserved APPn markers.

The problem you face is that the applications need to be able to read the metadata that you write.